# Manipulate lists by applying a function

Tags: list-manipulation

So I have this:

```
finalData ={{{7.26443, Log[3276304]}, 1.33309*10^8}, {{7.14221, Log[2458144]},1.33309*10^7}}
```

Now I want my list to be manipulated, so I get this:

```
{{{7.26443, Log[3276304]}, f[1.33309*10^8}], {{7.14221, Log[2458144]},f[1.33309*10^7}]}
```

i have tried it with     `Map[ErrorBar, finalData[[All, 2]]]`
but it isn't working
.

Comment: You should provide code that someone would be able to copy and paste instead of an image

Comment: `finalData = Map[ErrorBar, finalData[[All,2]]]`

Comment: i am sorry, I have refreshed my question. So I hope It is better now.

Comment: `MapAt[f, ## , {2}] & /@ finalData `

Comment: `{#[[1]], f[#[[2]]]} & /@ finalData`

Answer (score 1):

We now have `SubsetMap`:

```
SubsetMap[Map[f], finalData, {All, 2}]
```